# How to access specific SRA sequences within an SRP file?

Tags: linux, ncbi, sra

How do you get a specific 100 SRA sequences from a Bioproject which contains 400 runs, when you don't need all of them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome @kirtikulanthaivel, the answer is very likely to involve the SRA toolkit (freeware), if it is doable. How to apply this is more challenging because the question isn't clear. Could you supply a reproducible example? It does not need to be the data set(s) you are interested in.

Comment: I actually wanted to know how a specific number of SRR runs, for example 100 of them from a total of 400 in an accession list can be downloaded at a time. Problem solved, thanks to a friend. Thank you all anyway.